# Matching an argument using a regex?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have the following string:

```
"=if(WildMatch(PROD,'A','B','C','D'),PROD,'Other'"
```

I want to extract what's between WildMatch( and the first comma (in this case the word PROD) 
How can I do this ?

Comment: The regex pattern to match "PROD" would be `PROD`.

Comment: but how to write the pattern , knowing that the keyword PROD will change in the futur so I want to extract what's between WildMatch( and the first comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\(([^,(]+)(?=,)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDZVCp/1)

OR if you want specifically for `WildMatch`, you can use this:

`WildMatch\(([^,(\n]+)(?=,)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDZVCp/2)

**Explanation(for 1st regex):**

- `\(` - matches `(` literally
- `([^,(]+)` - matching and capturing 1+occurrences of any character that is neither a `,` nor a `(`. The data captured in this group is what you need.
- `(?=,)` - Positive lookahead to validate that whatever is matched in the previous steps is followed by a comma `,`

In both the cases, you can get the required data from group1 of each match as shown below:

**VBScript Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim objRE, strTest, objMatches, match
strTest = "=if(WildMatch(PROD,'A','B','C','D'),PROD,'Other'"
Set objRE = New RegExp
objRE.Global=True
objRE.Pattern="\(([^,(]+)(?=,)"
Set objMatches = objRE.Execute(strTest)
For Each match In objMatches
    MsgBox match.Submatches.Item(0)
Next
Set objMatches = Nothing
Set objRE = Nothing
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your desire value should be in group 1:

```
WildMatch\((.+?),
```

- **+? Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (*lazy*)

Check the result here: https://regex101.com/r/bQop74/1